# How to combine multiple rows from three tables into one single string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have three tables that store different kinds of data according to an admission process.

The first table ([dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado]) stores the basic contact info of the future student. The second table ([dbo].[Checklist_Documentos]) stores the names and ID's for the documents that the student must have to complete the admission process. The third table ([dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado]) stores the documents that the student has effectively brought to the admissions office.

I need to combine this info so that we can export an excel file holding all the contact info, and the document's checklist for each student.

So, let's say table 1 haves 4 records:
[dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado]

[image]

The second table ([dbo].[Checklist_Documentos]) haves eight records, different types of requested documents:
[image]

And the third table ([dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado]) haves 16 records:

[image]

What I need is that this three tables get combined according to the aspirant's ID:

[image]

So far, I've tried to different types of codes:

**Code 1**

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[ID],
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[Name],
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[ProgramID],
    [dbo].[Checklist_Documentos].[Document] 
FROM [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado] 

INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado]
    ON [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado].[IdForm] = [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[ID]

INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Checklist_Documentos]
    ON [dbo].[Checklist_Documentos].[ID] = [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado].[IdDoc]
```

This one gets one line per each document, so the name and other records are repeated according to the number of documents that the aspirant has on his folder.

**Code 2**

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[ID],
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[Nombres],
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[Apellido1],
    (STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado].[IdDocumento] AS varchar(max))
        FROM [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado]
        WHERE([dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[ID] = [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado].[IdForm])
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS [Docs]
FROM [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado]
```

This code get's and error: 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.

I appreciate all your help and comments.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of pictures can you post actual ddl and sample data in a consumable format? https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your **Code 2**, you can fix the error by doing the `CAST` **before** you do the concatenation.

In other words:

```
(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST([dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado].[IdDocumento] AS varchar(max))
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I haven't noticed it.

In order to complete the request, I added an inner join, so that the third table would bring the document name and not only the ID...

Answer (score 2):

@Tab Alleman gave me the hint on the answer, I haven't noticed that error in the writing. It solved the issue, but the code would only bring the document's ID from the second table ([dbo].[Checklist_Documentos]) So I added an INNER JOIN to combine the data:

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[ID],
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[Nombres],
    [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[Apellido1],
    (STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST([dbo].[Checklist_Documentos].[Documento] AS varchar(max))
        FROM [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado]
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[Checklist_Documentos] 
            ON [dbo].[Checklist_Documentos].[ID] = [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado].[IdDocumento] 
        WHERE([dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado].[ID] = [dbo].[Checklist_Pregrado].[IdForm])
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS [Docs]
FROM [dbo].[Inscripciones_Pregrado]
```